# RTL8192cu wifi Authentication request to the driver failed

Tags: raspbian, wifi, driver

The device is being picked up by my pi. I also checked to make sure the 8192cu module is being loaded by the kernel as well. But I simply cannot connect to my wifi. I have tried multiple methods. I have used the provided wifi_config gui. I get the following error message.

```
Authentication to the driver failed
```

So I tried to manually go and configure my /etc/network/interfaces file using the following options

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
         wpa-ssid = "foo"
         wpa-psk = "bar"
```

I have also tried using wicd-curses.
All three methods are finding the network just fine, however they all seem to be running issues when trying to connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test this in a basic way, first stop the networking daemon:

```
service networking stop
```

Edit `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`; you need root privileges.  There should be only one entry for `network`, like this:

```
network={
    ssid="yourSSID"
    psk="yourPassPhrase"
}
```

And other than the first two lines (not shown), that's all you need in that file. If it doesn't look like that, create a backup copy of the file and change it so it does.  You've already confirmed the kernel 8192cu module is loaded.  Apparently `wlan0` is the interface name, double check that with `ip link`.  If there's a wlan0, we're good.

```
wpa_supplicant -d -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -i wlan0
```

Give it about 10-15s. That will run in the foreground so you will now need to open a second terminal and run:

```
dhclient -v wlan0
```

If you get a lease, congratulations, everything works.  Confirm with `ip link` which should show an IP address associated with wlan0.

If you can't get this to work -- e.g. `wpa_supplicant` fails -- it is probably a driver issue.  Have a look at [this list of wifi adapters](http://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters) known to work/not work on the pi and see if yours is there.